# Can you omit the 的 after 举办 in 北京奥运会是2008年举办的？

Tags: grammar

I know that this sentence is correct:

北京奥运会是2008年举办的。

But can you omit the “的” that is after the verb “举办”？

Like this:

北京奥运会是2008年举办[ ]。

I think, I have read some sentences that has omitted the “的” after a verb in the end of a sentence, but I'm not quite sure.

If you can, please provide me some examples.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> 北京奥运会是2008年举办的。

"北京奥运会是2008年举办的" is a [topic + comment/opinion] sentence

- Topic: 北京奥运会 (Beijing Olympics)
- Comment: 是 2008年 举办的 (is hosted by 2008)

*(It is obviously wrong, it makes 2008年 the subject. I will state the correct sentence later in this post)*

The '的' here is a [possessive marker]. It marks the omitted object to be possessed by [2008年]

> 2008年 举办的(项目)
>
> 2008年 is the **subject**; *项目 (or other noun refers to 北京奥运会) is the omitted object*

The correct sentence should be:

> "北京奥运会是**在** 2008年 举办的" (Beijing Olympics is hosted **in** 2008)
>
> *the subject '北京' is omitted, "北京奥运会是(北京)在 2008年 举办的"*

In this sentence,  '的' is an [adjective marker]. It turns "在 2008年举办" into an adjective phrase "在 2008年 举办的"

This adjective phrase describes 北京奥运会 (Beijing Olympics *that is hosted in 2008*)

**'的' cannot be omitted in this sentence.**

To avoid using 的, you can change this [topic + comment/opinion] sentence into a [SVO] sentence and write "(北京)在 2008年 举办北京奥运会" - "(Beijing) held the Beijing Olympic Games in 2008"

Since we do not omit the subject '北京' here, we can omit the '北京' in '北京奥运会' instead -- "北京在 2008年 举办(北京)奥运会"

Comment: I read `[在]` as indicating 在 is optional, but I think you mean to say the opposite:  在 is required.  Otherwise the correct sentence is the same as the original.

Comment: @Ben Jackson  I was trying to make it stand out, yes, it is needed in this sentence, otherwise, 2008年 would become the subject

Answer (score -1):

Let's say this in English.

> The Olmpics was held in 2008.

The held can be either considered passive voice or as a adjective. Your sentence

> 北京奥运会是2008年举办。

matches neither. 举办 is a verb. But with 的, it becomes a valid adjective.

Using passive voice is not encouraged here, which would be:

> 北京奥运会在2008年被举办了。

Unless you really want to say this in a very objective manner, it is very uncommon to say it this way, especially without any adjectives or adverbs.

Comment: `北京奥运会在2008年举办` is the passive term.  It is kinda strange why you want to use `被举办了` 。 `被xx 了`  in today mainland China is a sarcasm.

Comment: I have already said it is very uncommon and not encouraged to say this and this is just a translation. And 被字句 isn't alway sarcasm. @mootmoot